# limiting LAG in SQL

Tags: sql, lag

I am using the LAG function to return a previous record. Since records are not necessarily consecutive in regards to dates I decided to go the LAG route (if there's a better way please share). The issue that I'm running into is that it gives me all records when I only want one per item. How do I go about limiting results?

Here's a data set for item a per say:

| PO Number | BillingDate | DiscountRecNo | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0646546541 | 12/12/2021 | 4654064 | 4656 |
| 4651132066 | 10/13/2021 | 8984653 | 4655 |
| 4654113866 | 11/13/2021 | 6464651 | 4656 |
| 9865413488 | 08/05/2021 | 5461984 | 4655 |

For this example I only want PO Number 9865413488 for item 4655 and 4654113866 for 4656.

Here's what I have

```
            LAG(LT.CondRecNo, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY LT.BillingDate DESC) AS PREVIOUSCONDRECNO
```

Comment: Which record would you want? Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by item order by billinddate desc) as rn from t) x where rn = 2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you dont need lag() just need row_number()

```
   with cte as
    (select *,row_number()over(partition by item order by BillingDate) rn
    ) select a.* from cte whre rn=1
```